# Rails tag_id3v1 mp3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, taglib-ruby

Rails 4.2 ap and taglib-ruby gem

I have tried a few approaches to tag my audio files using taglib-ruby.

I have tried as a carrierwave process, and now, I am trying to tag after_save.

My question, if I am doing a callback after_save:

```
 def tag_id3v1(tags)
   TagLib::MPEG::File.open(file.path) do |file|
   tag = file.id3v1_tag(true)
   tag.title = :title
   file.save
end
```

end

what should my file path be? I have tried :file, :file_name, and the uploader version url, #{track.mp3.url}

I am trying to reopen the saved files and write the tags to the files. Does anyone have any hints on the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally

```
TagLib::MPEG::File.open(file.file) do |file|
```

Always something like, "file.file". No matter the approach, that is what did the trick for me.

I ended up doing this in a carrierwave callback inside of a :version. Final code

```
version :mp3 do
  process :convert => [:mp3] 

  def full_filename(for_file)
   "#{super.chomp(File.extname(super))}.mp3"
  end  

  after :store, :tag_id3v2

  end


 def tag_id3v2(for_file)
  TagLib::MPEG::File.open(file.file) do |file|
  tag = file.id3v2_tag(true)
  tag.title = "#{model.title}"
  file.save
 end
 end 

(...)
```